# Permanently Push To The End of An Array

Tags: php, arrays

## How can I do the following:

```
$x = array();
$x[] = '1';
$x[] = '2';
```

But have it added permanently to the array?

I have idea on how we could try doing it:

- Make a new .txt file;
- Write for example: `1~2~3`;
- Use `file_get_contents` to apply it to a variable `$y`;
- Apply `explode()`;
- Now we can do:

`x[] = y[0]; x[] = y[1]; x[] = y[2];`

- Add that to a foreach loop;
- Then somehow use fwrite() or file_put_contents() maybe? to add the variable I want to add to the array so we would use fwrite or something to add to the .txt file?

But im wondering is that the best way of doing it?

Comment: are you saying you want to modify the .php file programmatically so that the `$x = array('1','2');`?

Comment: Yes, Like for example if someone does ?v=30 in the url using GET it will grab it and like add it to the end of the array safely and permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serialize` on your array, which converts it into a string that you can write to a file

```
file_put_contents("myfile",serialize($x));
```

and `unserialize` to convert the string back into an array

```
$x = unserialize(file_get_contents("myfile"));
```

If you only need to append values to the very end of the array, you can use `file_put_contents` with the `FILE_APPEND` option, which is faster than reading the entire array into memory and writing it back to disk

```
file_put_contents("myfile", "1\n", FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents("myfile", "2\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

and read the array using `file` (which uses `\n` as a delimiter by default)

```
$x = file("myfile");
```

Comment: Yes but how can I append/push a new string/value to the end of the array?

Comment: @John123 the same way `$x[] = 'newvalue';`

Comment: So after we unserialize add the new value's then serialize?

Comment: @John123 yes you can use `serialize` if you want to write the updated array back to disk again

Comment: For the new edit you made, Why isn't serialize anywhere?

Comment: @John123 the new edit stores 1 raw value per line. the advantage of using serialize instead of storing raw values is that you can store arrays that are many levels deep and can store a mix of complex data structures vs only strings. only use the `FILE_APPEND` method if your array consists of strings and is very large (10k+ elements) and you only need to append elements

Comment: Well all I need to do is add a value/string/variable anywhere in my array either in the start end or middle I couldnt care less, And all I need to do is add one value per page load what im doing is adding a ID to the array by doing x[] = $id; and thats all, So the serialize is better cause I still need to load the whole array when the page loads anyway so loading it in full isn't a waste of time or resources :)

Comment: Oh, It seems like it wont like append, Like I dont want the file to change to the newest one I want it appended to the array, Is my only option the edit you made?

Comment: Nvm, I worked it out, I had to file_get_contents and unserialize it before it which i knew but I forgot to make serialize unserialize and the newvalue bit the same array name/variable name

Answer (score 0):

To save anything "permanently", you need some kind of persistent storage. A txt file would work, database, even cookies code work depending on what you are saving.

[file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

[MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Comment: Yes but would that be the best way, Is there no way to do it directly in the same PHP file?

Comment: Not really possible. Storing in a text file or a database is the "best way", and in most cases, the only way.

Comment: I recommend a database, but it really depends on what you are saving, why you are saving and how much you are saving.

Comment: Well that is true, There will be a ton of arrays but I couldn't really care less. xD Once it gets to a huge amount ill move to DB

Comment: Then see @FuzzyTree answer. It is not that much work to add a database though.

Comment: Yeah, I use DB's A LOT which is why im trying to avoid it.